# Add Grafana Variables dropdown to specific panel

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable, grafana-dashboard

I have a grafana variable which is displayed at the top of dashboard.
[image]

I want this variable dropdown only to appear in a specific panel .eg some where inside the panel .Not at the top of the dashboards. as I have several panels in that dashboard and that dropdown is only related to one panel.

[image]

Comment: I don't think that this is possible today. Maybe you should vote for Feature request [Per-panel variables #8408](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/8408).